# Refreshing React with Express server

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-ec2, react-router, production

I have looked through the questions and can't seem to find the answer. There are similar ones but none that have helped.

Here is the deal. I am trying to refresh my React page on any page but home i.e. https://amazingdomain/nextpage

I know, if I am on this page and I refresh I will get the Express 404 because it doesn't know what to send. My Server is hosted on AWS as an EC2 instance and my Frontend is hosted on a popular hosting site. Everything works fine until I try to refresh on a page other than home. I am at a loss here. I have search and can't find my answer.

My React Router looks like:

```
      render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
              <Route exact path="/firstPage" component={FirstPage} />
              <Route exact path="/secondPage" component={SecondPage} />
              <Route exact path="/thirdPage" component={ThirdPage} />
              <Route path='/*' exact={true} component={Page404} />
            </Switch>
          </div>  
        </Router>

    );
  }
}
```

My server looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const config = require('./config.js');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


//Here is my attempt to get the page to refresh
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server Running on Port: ${port}`);
});
```

I know there is a hashrouter and I would like to avoid using it. I know there is browserrouter as well. I have tried but I still get the 404 error.

I want to be able to go to https://amazingdomain/firstpage hit f5 and go right back to that same page in production. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If Express is serving your react front-end application, you would want to update `res.sendFile` to send the `index.html` of the built react application. If Express is NOT serving your react front-end then you need to do the redirect on the "popular hosting site". https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment has a number of popular hosting solutions and provide solutions for redirecting to `index.html`.

Comment: Hey @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks for the reply. I am not serving the html file from express. Does this mean there is a way to do this in react or is there something on the hosting site I dont know about? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you would need to refer to the hosting sites configuration to redirect all requests to index.html, this could be a dedicated config file in your source used during deploy or could be some dashboard settings. If you try and continue having issues, update your question with what you have tried.