# Refreshing React page

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-ec2, react-router

I'm back ([Refreshing React with Express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124847/refreshing-react-with-express-server)). I am hoping to figure out this issue.

**Quick recap:** I am trying to refresh my react website. If I go to www.domain.com/about I will get the:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

same if I click on the button to get to /about and hit refresh I will get this error.

**My goal** 
To be able to go to my site, click on another page (i.e. domain.com/anotherpage) hit f5 for refresh and get the same page.

**I understand:**

The problem is that React just changes the URL when I click on my React app button or link to go to a different page. Then when I refresh it looks for www.domain.com/whatever. Since there is nothing for it, it returns 404.

I also know that if I can get my React app to direct all traffic to index.html. React will handle the rest.

**What I have tried:**

In my previous post, it was suggested to use my hosting site to redirect traffic to index.html. However, my hosting site lets me adjust the DNS for subdomains but nothing after it. (ie. www.subdomain.domain.com works fine but www.domain.com/whatever doesn't) which I expected but I thought I would try.

I do have an express app however, it doesn't serve the files it just waits for a button to be pressed and then does stuff. I don't need to the server to run to have the website up.

I have tried creating a route in express for this and it looks like:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

I still get the same 404 error with this.

I have also added an index.html to my server. Thinking it needed the .html file to send. (Thought it might be good).

**What I don't know**

Where does React look for index.html in production? When I look in the build files under asset-manifest.json there is an "index.html": "/index.html" line of code. Is there where it finds the index file? If so, can I change this to go to index.html on every page request?

Obviously I want the user to be able to refresh the page and get back to it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By any chance is your front end hosted in Netlify?

Comment: @ajthyng no it's not. Would this help if it was?